# Why Sina.Cosb and Cosa.Sinb are two different identities?

Tags: geometry, functions, trigonometry

[image]

Should not *Sina.Cosb* and *Cosa.Sinb* be same if we exchange a and b? Why there is an extra negative sign for *Cosa.Sinb*?

Comment: Because  $\sin(b-a)=-\sin(a-b)$

Comment: Thank you. I understand now.

Comment: Recal that $\sin a\cos b+\cos a \sin b=\sin (a+b) $ and $\sin a\cos b-\cos a \sin b=\sin (a-b) $.

Comment: I think it is rather silly to have both formulas in the same table of formulas though, isn't it? After all, if you have $\cos x \sin y$ you can just write it as $\sin y \cos x$ and then apply the first formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should not $\sin a\cos b$ and $\cos a \sin b$ be same if we exchange $a$ and $b$? Why there is an extra negative sign for $\cos a\sin b$?

Because if you exchange $a$ and $b$, you get the term $$\sin(b-a),$$

which is the same as $$\color{blue}-\sin(a-b).$$